# Add webpart in Sharepoint Modern page using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

How can I add webpart using Powershell script in SharePoint online modern page?

Add Webpart using PowerShell script, I tried many more times to do that but got errors and warnings. can you help me solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the command [Add-PnPPageWebPart](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPPageWebPart.html?q=add-pnppagewebpart) from the PowerShell module Pnp.PowerShell

Sample of code:

```
$siteUrl = "https://my-tenant.sharepoit.com/sites/my-site"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive

$pageUrl = "home.aspx"
$page = Get-PnPPage -Identity $pageUrl

Add-PnPPageTextPart -Page $page -Text "Hello world!"

Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $page -DefaultWebPartType "List" -WebPartProperties @{ webRelativeListUrl = "/SitePages"}
```

Console:

[image: PowerShell script]

Result:

[image: SharePoint webpart page]

What is your problem?

What kind of errors do you have?